# How do I expand a multipart CAB in cmd?

Tags: command-line, cab

I have successfully created a multi part CAB file using makecab and a ddf file:

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=package.*
.set DiskDirectoryTemplate=Disk
.Set MaxDiskSize=10485760 ; 10 MB
.Set Cabinet=on
.Set Compress=on
; my files go here
```

This created a bunch of files "package.1", "package.2", etc.
How do I expand these files?
I tried: **expand Disk\package.1 -F:* Disk\Temp**, which worked for a single part file, but fails for multi part cab with the error:

```
 One or more files could not be expanded. Delta Package Expander Returned 0x80070032

 Expanding File disk\package.1 Incomplete, Error Code=0x80070032
 Error Description: The request is not supported.
```

NOTE: I cannot use any external tools not included in default installation of Windows XP. Otherwise I would just use 7zip. Btw. 7zip does extract these files no problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the command extrac32.

> Unlike expand.exe, this was intended for use with Microsoft Internet Explorer. Later, it became a part of the Windows installation. As this is not a console application, it's not very interactive with command line. Typing 'extrac32' without any parameters will simply load the utility which will terminate immediately.
>
> To read the directives, enter
>
> `extrac32 |more`
>
> [image]

source: http://researchbin.blogspot.de/2012/05/making-and-extracting-cab-files-in.html